# `Failed to execute script` al abrir ejecutable en otro ordenador

Tags: python, tkinter, exe, pyinstaller

He hecho un juego usando `tkinter` y al convertirlo en `.exe` con `pyinstaller` funciona en mi ordenador, pero al abrirlo en otros aparece:

```
Failed to execute script <nombre_del_juego>
```

Lo he seguido intentando y resulta que si saco la imagen que puse sí que funciona en otros dispositivos.

Uso `Windows 10` de `64bits` con `Python 3.7` de `32bits` y he usado el comando `pyinstaller mi_juego.py --onefile --noconsole -i icono.ico`

Así incluyo la imagen:

```
playa=PhotoImage(file=r'C:/Users/DarkC/Downloads/python/archivos/playa.gif')
canva.create_image(0,0,anchor=NW,image=playa)
```

Comment: Sin más información va a ser complicado ayudar, puede ser que estés **usando módulos locales o algún otro recurso no incluidos en el exe**, uso de rutas absolutas que obviamente no existirán en otro sistema, etc.

Comment: Mirate https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/when-things-go-wrong.html, puede servirte de guía. Al construir el exe elimina la opción `--windowed` si la tienes (para que se muestre la shell) y habilita la depuración con `--debug`.Ejecuta el exe en el otro sistema a ver que te muestra por la consola.

Comment: Dinos qué version de python estas usando, qué sistema operativo y el comando que usaste con `PyInstaller` por si hay algo raro. Yo me he encontrado con problemas cuando he instalado python de 64 bits en Windows de 64bits y luego al intentar ejecutarlo en otro Windows de 32bits me ha dado errores.

Comment: Como bien dice Rodriguez, algo compilado con PyInstaller se compila solo para ese sistema "exacto". Si compilas en un windows 10, no funcionará en un Windows 7. Si compilas en un Windows XP, no funcionará en un Windows 10, etc. En caso de que no sea ese el problema, asegurate de que tienes todos los archivos necesarios en las carpetas de forma relativa y no falta ninguno. Ejemplo: `/images/logo.jpg` en lugar de `c:/pepito/juego/images/logo.jpg`

Comment: No es así, de hecho compilando en “Windows10 64bits con Python 32bits” funciona correctamente en Windows7 de 32 bits, o al menos todos los scripts que he compilado lo han hecho sin problema. Simplemente respeta la plataforma y arquitectura de Python

Comment: Por lo que comentas, estás incluyendo una imagen en el ejecutable. Necesitamos saber cómo lo haces.

Answer (score 0):

```
playa=PhotoImage(file=r'C:/Users/DarkC/Downloads/python/archivos/playa.gif')
```

Quizás me equivoque, pero si tienes esta ruta en tu ordenador personal, en esa forma de ruta absoluta es algo normal que no funcione en otros ordenadores, ya que la ruta podrá ser la misma, pero el nombre de usuario siempre cambiará entre ordenadores; en este caso, si tienes el usuario "DarkC", y en otro equipo no tienes el mismo nombre de usuario, el programa lógicamente no funcionará.

Supongo que este no será el problema que tienes, porque sería un error un poco obvio.